# Variable displaying as NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, nan

I have a variable that keeps showing up as `NaN`. I can't figure out why it is doing this.

This doesn't show up as `NaN`, it displays the value it should (from a jQuery UI slider).

```
var gdHours = $("#gdhours").val();
```

But my next bit of code always displays as `NaN`, and it keeps the rest of the calculations in the function from working. Shown here:

```
var gdCost = $("#gdcost").val(gdHours*20);
```

I have tried using `parseInt` and `parseFloat` and it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: what kind of values do you provide in the field #gdhours ?

Comment: `gdHours` is probably a string. You can't multiply a string by 20.

Comment: Can you try `alert((""+gdHours).length)` to make sure there aren't any sneaky hidden characters around?

Comment: use console.log(typeof gdHours), to get an idea. Did you use parseInt in the gdHours variable or in the gdCost?

Comment: is the element with #gdcost id set to gdHours * 20 or is the gdCost NaN?

Comment: the first one is a getter, the second one is a setter function...

Comment: typeof tells me it is a number. The alert first told me 1 then when I did it the second time told me 2, not sure what that's all about. I tried parseInt on both gdHours and gdCost. gdHours displayed as a number whether I parsed it or not. It had no affect on gdCost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setter val(NEW_VALUE) returns the jQuery object. You could write

```
var gdCost = $("#gdcost").val(gdHours*20).val();
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks alot!! As you can tell I am new to coding, so any help is very appreciated.

Comment: also, you'd better add second parameter to `parseInt` call (which defines radix) like `parseInt(gdHours, 10)` to prevent invalid parsing for this situation with leading zero. read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Good point about the radix in general, though actually in this case parseInt isn't necessary at all because the value comes from a jQuery UI slider. I'm going to remove it from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a parameter to the `val(...)` function, it returns the object, not the value. So in the second example is equivalent to the following:

```
$("#gdcost").val(gdHours*20);
var gdCost = $("#gdcost");
```

So the jQuery object is returned, not the value of the element.

jQuery does this to support function call chaining.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast an integer like

```
foo = parseInt($('#foo').val());
```

because input type="text" may return a string by using val() and you cant multiply a string